# How to install yarn package on VS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, corepack

As I am running the corepack enable it is showing me
Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'
Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'

I am expecting the command to initiate and the yarn package get installed further by running
yarn --version.

Answer (score 0):

with npm install -g yarn it was showing error something like permission denied
then i Run the code
"sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}"
then it asked the password
then i tried the code and it worked..